# How to add similar posts in Detailview in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-1.11

I want to add similar posts section to my blog django application in Class DetailView on detail page

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Deal
    template_name = 'deals/detail.html'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at [Ask] to understand how to post good questions. You need to be more specific. What have you tried? What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Deal
    template_name = 'deals/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context[post] = post
        return context
```

get_context_data method is responsible for passing the data in template . the context is a dict so you and add your key value in this dict and access it form template.

```
<html>
<body>
{{post}}
</body>
</html>
```

what ever data you added it to your context dict the you can access it from template with key.